# How to Clear OutputCache for Website without Restarting App

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

Is there a way clear or reset the outputcache for an entire website without a restart?

I'm just starting to use outputcache on a site and when I make a mistake in setting it up I need a page I can browse to that will reset it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

 Dim path As String
 path="/AbosoluteVirtualPath/OutputCached.aspx"
 HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(path)

End Sub
```

Comment: This answer does not in fact clear the cache for the "entire web site" as specified in original question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to controller or to page code:

```
HttpContext.Cache.Insert("Page", 1);
Response.AddCacheItemDependency("Page");
```

To clear output cachne use the following command in controller:

```
    HttpContext.Cache.Remove("Page");
```