# Clear partial output caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax, fragment-caching

I have a page that has controls that are output caches (partial output caching). These are setup like this:

```
[PartialCaching(86400, null, null, "campaign.whatwhere", true)]
public partial class controls_LatestEnquiriesListCached : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

...
```

With

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if (custom == "campaign.whatwhere")
    {
        return (CampaignManager.CurrentCampaign.DefaultWorkTypeId ?? 0).ToString() + (CampaignManager.CurrentCampaign.DefaultEnquiryAreaId ?? 0).ToString();
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

In `Global.asax`

How can I setup so I can clear this output cache on a specific page?

Is it possible to setup like `MyPageWithCachedControl.aspx?ClearCache=true`???

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565239/any-way-to-clear-flush-remove-outputcache

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101/how-to-clear-outputcache-for-website-without-restarting-app

Comment: How are these exact duplicates?

Comment: You should use HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(path) to clear the output cache where path is the virtual absolute path of the user control as specified in the http://stackoverflow.com/a/37167/30594

Answer (score 0):

You can create an aspx page that does nothing but clears cache.  You can take the querystring parameter and have it delete by cache key.

Or you can try to find and ASP.NET cache manager.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(path)` to clear the output cache where path is the virtual absolute path of the user control as specified in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/37167/30594

Answer (score 0):

Use `HTTPResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(pathofpage)` to clear the cache of a particular page.

For example:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/form1.aspx");
}
```